# Is it possible to connect multiple Bluetooth client devices to same UUID (service) hosted by server?

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, android-bluetooth, simultaneous

**Problem Statement :**
Device A has android bluetooth server app running and listening for connection (with uuid say XXXX-1234).

I want to write a client application (which will use same UUID : XXXX-1234 to connect) and which can be install on multiple devices (B, C, D and so on upto 7 devices as per piconet) and all of them simultaneously connects and remain connected to the server. ***The aim is to send common piece of data from server app to all android client app.***

before implementing this, ***I have couple of questions as below :***

1) Is it possible to connect multiple client with the server app with same UUID?

- as per my understanding the first device (B) should connect without any issue, but when i shall try to connect next device (C) then i am unsure if it allow the connection ? since the listening socket in device A is already connected with device B...

2) Does the SDP lookup lists down those UUID also which are already connected?

- I am asking this because if it **doesn't** then i can avoid connecting to UUID which is already used by other app.
- so instead of using just 1 UUID in server, set of UUIDs can be hard coded in server to create multiple sockets and the same set can be used on the client app to check if any of the UUID is available and can be used to initiate connection.

*Since same client app will be install on multiple devices, i want each app to connect to only 1 UUID/Service of server app. It should **NOT** create connection with all UUID if it finds that all UUIDs are available.*

I will really appreciate any leads.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to add further, I want to know about the SDP lookup results because i don't want the app to try to connect to all the uuids one by one to see if it can connect.

Because as per android bluetooth docs **connect() is a blocking call** and if the app checks for connection one by one for all UUIDs then it will take hell lot of time and time to connect will increase as and when devices keeps on connecting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible if server supports such connections. I am not sure about android but Bluetooth does not limit that.

B;uetooth uses UUID only to describe services. The RFCOMM connection (I guess you are talking about RFCOMM) uses something known as Channel to execute connection. You can have few identical UUID running on different channels. And the clients connect to the channel number. The channel number can be from 1 to 31.

So back to yuor task. If Android does not allow to accept more than single connection on the same RFCOMM channel you can do the following (as we usualy do for BlueSoleil that allows only single connection to a server):

1. Start first server with your UUID on let say channel 2.
2. Once client connected remove the SDP and start next server with the same UUID but with channel 3.
3. Do the same for each connected client cinreasing channel number.
4. When client disconnects put server on hold if other running so you can turn it on when new client connected.

Something like that. But I think Android should allow to connect to same channel more than 1 client.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.